# SQL query for monitoring DB2 z/OS

Tags: db2, zos

I'm new to this type of problems. I'm looking for SQL query that will allow me to monitor processes on DB2 z/OS.
I tried to use this query:

```
SELECT session_auth_id,
       application_handle,
       elapsed_time_sec,
       activity_state,
       rows_read,
       SUBSTR(stmt_text,1,200)
FROM sysibmadm.mon_current_sql
ORDER BY elapsed_time_sec DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

and this query:

```
SELECT agent_id, 
            Substr(appl_name, 1, 20) AS APPLNAME, 
            elapsed_time_min, 
            Substr(authid, 1, 10)    AS AUTH_ID, 
            agent_id, 
            appl_status, 
            Substr(stmt_text, 1, 30) AS STATEMENT 
     FROM   sysibmadm.long_running_sql 
     WHERE  elapsed_time_min > 0 
     ORDER  BY elapsed_time_min desc 
     FETCH first 5 ROWS only
```

but they work only on DB2 LUW. Anny suggestion will be appreciated!

I tried to monitor active processes on DB2 z/OS.

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are - unfortunately, but also to a degree understandably - platform specific. DB2 LUW, DB2 for z/OS, DB2 for i. They are very compatible when it comes to data and the SQL language, but the task-related table functions are different.

DB2 V11 for z/OS table functions are documented in https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-list-supported-built-in. There is also a good article here [Db2 for z/OS: Long-Running Transactions Revisited](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/db2-zos-long-running-transactions-revisited-thomas-baumann).

You won't have access to the SQL statement itself on z/OS. Quite different sets of information are provided. In short, the task-related table functions provided by DB2 for z/OS are:

1. DSNADM.ADMIN_TASK_LIST()
2. DSNADM.TASK_STATUS()
3. SYSIBMADM.BLOCKING_THREADS()

Whether they are useful to you depends on which information you are after.

N.B.:
IBM i (AS400) has gone a different route and provides a plethora of information through table functions.

Hope this helps.